# Multi threading cURL request?

Tags: bash, multithreading, shell, curl

I want to generate list of numbers and make a http request and save the result using cURL and jq on ubuntu.

I already wrote single thread using FOR loop and it's works but I want to add threading to my script to works faster.

```
    for i in `seq 12345 12550 `; do echo $i ;curl -s -k -X $'GET' \
-H $'Host: example.com' -H $'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36' -H $'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' -H $'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H $'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fa;q=0.8' -H $'Connection: close' \
$'https://example.com/pages/json/'$i'/list' | jq ".files[]"; done
```

How can I add threading or parallels to my script to speed up my process?

My goal is make a bash script that receive arguments for numbers range and threads counts from user and save the result for each request to the specific path by requested number name.

```
$script.sh -numbers 12345-12550 -threads 100 -outpath ~/result/
```

Comment: Multi-threading multiple API calls is likely to be interpreted as abuse and get your IP/Application/Host banned or at least throttled. API providers usually sets limits on daily allowed requests and implements paging and result counts. Check with the API's TOS what rate/volume and features are allowed before you implement something potentially abusive.

Comment: @LéaGris I already checks my limitation, not any issue about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
doit() {
  i="$1"
  echo $i
  curl -s -k -X $'GET' \
    -H $'Host: example.com' -H $'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36' -H $'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' -H $'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H $'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fa;q=0.8' -H $'Connection: close' \
    $'https://example.com/pages/json/'$i'/list' |
    jq ".files[]"
}
export -f doit

seq 12345 12550 | parallel -j100 --results ~/result/{} doit
```

Comment: Thanks! works perfect! How can I add additional step to processing JQ result and if contains "***" in response save the seq number in result.txt ? Example: If 12345 contains *** in response, save the 12345 in result.txt .

Comment: doit() {
  i="$1"
  echo $i
  if curl -s -k -X $'GET' \
    -H $'Host: example.com' -H $'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36' -H $'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' -H $'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H $'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fa;q=0.8' -H $'Connection: close' \
    $'https://example.com/pages/json/'$i'/list' |
  jq '.files[]|contains("***")' | grep true ; then echo $i >> result.txt 
  fi
}
export -f doit

seq 12345 12550 | parallel -j100 --results ~/result/{} doit

Comment: @nerdg33k That solution has a slight risk of race condition if $i is large enough: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#Non-atomic_writes_with_xargs_-P In your use case it is probably OK.

Answer (score 1):

If `curl --version` says that you have version 7.66.0 or newer, then you can use `-Z`/`--parallel` to do transfers in parallel. `--parallel-max <num>` sets a limit on the number of simultaneous transfers (default limit is 50).

But to use that, you need to specify the target URLs in a single invocation of `curl`. One way to do that is to use curl's URL globbing (it's described in `man curl`). For example, to fetch a range from 1 to 100:

```
curl 'https://example.com/pages/json/[1-100]/list'
```

A step counter may also be given (e.g. `[1-30:10]` for `1`, `11`, `21`). Even without `-Z`, this should be more efficient as curl will be able to re-use connections. It will also allow the use of `#1` to have a special meaning in `--output` filenames (this is described in the curl manual and will do what I think you mean by `save the result for each request to the specific path by requested number name`).

BTW, instead of `-H $'Connection: close'`, you might prefer to use `-H 'Connection: keep-alive'` (ask to keep the connection open as you are making multiple requests, and `$''` quoting is for processing C style backslash escapes which I don't think you want to do here).

> My goal is ...
>
> ```
> $script.sh -numbers 12345-12550 -threads 100 -outpath ~/result/
> ```

Here's an idea for numbers and threads (simply given as the first and second positional parameters here - option parsing is up to you):

```
#!  /bin/sh   -

range=${1:?}
parallel=$2

url="https://example.com/pages/json/[$range]/list"
out='example_page_#1.json'

ua="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 \
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36"

curl -qfsS --compressed ${parallel:+-Z --parallel-max "$parallel"} \
  -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*'    \
  -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate'               \
  -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fa;q=0.8'     \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive'                       \
  -A "$ua" -o "$out" "$url"
```

```
$ chmod +x example
$ ./example 01-15  5
$ ls
example_page_01.json  example_page_06.json  example_page_11.json
example_page_02.json  example_page_07.json  example_page_12.json
example_page_03.json  example_page_08.json  example_page_13.json
example_page_04.json  example_page_09.json  example_page_14.json
example_page_05.json  example_page_10.json  example_page_15.json
```

This saves each transfer to its own `example_page_N.json` file (in the current directory). You can do any processing with `jq` afterwards. Maybe:

```
for f in example_page_*.json
  jq '.files[]' < "$f" > "files_$f"
done
```

I noticed in a comment that you want a single output file with the number of each result based on whether or not `.files[]` contains "***". Depending on the json data, you might be able to do that in a single pipeline with `jq` (but that would be a different question to "Multi threading cURL request?").

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing would be to take the script you have and make it take inputs to run once, then create another script that calls that one with various values.

For example:

Script1.sh

```
echo "%1 Hello World" >> output.txt
```

Script2.sh

```
 for name in $namesList ;do
        ./Script1.sh $name &
 done
 wait


cat output.txt
Dave Hello World
Tom Hello World
...
```

Note: this is more of a beginners approach  but from there you can call functions like this etc and make it all one script.

See document on Jobs:
https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x9644.html

Comment: I didn't get any hint from your answer. Why I should use Script1.sh for name generation? simply put that single line action into DO section in Script2.sh. there is no any related information about my question.

Comment: I guess you where thrown off because I didn't include "curl statements. Also Yeah I didn't have time to look into curl threading or thought you would be able to work with such a thing but appears other have more faith in you. My point was to show you how you could start a for loop that would  start X requests and run them at once, the wait command would ensure the script kept running until finished. You can also throttle it by telling it to stall if number of jobs exceeds X which I didn't include in the pseudo code.